# $.post() Jquery post not working with a new array() to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery posting to a php page. A `var_dump($_POST);` on the php page returns null but if I do :

`$.post("test.php", {"script" : script} );`

everything works.

The reason I do not want to do it that way, is because the array can have variable arguments. Any help?

```
var arr = new Array();
arr["script"] = scrip;
arr["account"] = "max@hotmail.com";
arr["accounttag"] = "TH";


if (follow != "")
    arr["followtag"] = follow;
if (join != null)
    arr["join"] = join;

$.post("test.php", arr );

    //{"script" : script, "account" : "max@hotmail.com", "accounttag" : "TH"}  
    //works if used instead of arr

    ///test.php

    var_dump($_POST)
    array 0{null};
```

Comment: might `JSON.stringify()` be what you need? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: You want to send an object, not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `var arr` should be an `Object` not an `Array`.

Try something like:

```
var data = {
    script: scrip,
    account: "max@hotmail.com",
    accounttag: "TH"
}

if (follow != "")
    data.followtag = follow;
if (join != null)
    data.join = join;

$.post("test.php", data);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for explanation of `$.post`.